# Python 3.x. HTTP Error 403: Forbidden (даже с "User-agent")

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, request

Хочу написать программу, которая бы скачивала альбомы с музыкой. Для начала решил просто прочитать страницу. Однако если с другими сайтами такой проблемы нет, то с необходимым всего случается Response 403. Не помогло добавление даже "user agent", как советуют во всех гайдах. Что делать? Код привожу ниже:

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'

url = "https://2mz.me/"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
request.add_header('User-Agent', user_agent)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print(request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то намутили в том сайте, не стал разбираться, поэтому сделал через selenium.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/250935974ed34e10c7892e99e0e1d79ebf96c03c/html_parsing/2mz_me.py)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

try:
    driver.get('https://2mz.me/')
    print(f'Title: "{driver.title}"')

    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#tracks .item'):
        title = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.item-title').text
        author = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.item-author').text
        print(title, author)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Консоль:

```
Title: "2mz.me - слушать музыку онлайн или скачать бесплатно в mp3"
Minor Miyagi & Andy Panda
ТЫ ГОРИШЬ КАК ОГОНЬ SLAVA MARLOW
...
неболей Zivert, Баста
Поболело и прошло HENSY
```

Comment: Сам на Selenium переполз. А  вот за автоматический поиск автора и композиции отдельное спасибо

Comment: @ЕгорПриставка, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте и примите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :) К сожалению, не все сайты можно обычными средствами парсить, поэтому приходится использовать js-движки

Answer (score 3):

Кроме user-agent есть и другие заголовки, которые проверяются сайтом... Добавьте все, чтоб не гадать:

```
import requests


url = 'https://2mz.me/'
headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'uk,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

>>> r.status_code
200
```

Comment: Тут забыли закрыть кавычки для ключа: `'accept: text/html,` :) Работает, вы молодец :)

Comment: Странно, не увидел поля `sec-` в заголовках запроса, у вас они добавляются гугл хромом?

Comment: @gil9red поправил кавычки, спасибо! да, sec- добавляются (Version 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: А... понятно.. я у них попробовал ваш запрос (было 200), после начал убирать поля пока не наткнулся на 403, после стал возвращать поля и когда вернул все поля, все-равно 403, думаю что за нафиг, открываю сайт в браузере, а тот пишет про подозрительную активность по IP и предлагает ввести капчу. Сайт делали параноики :)

Comment: спасибо! теперь действительно теперь перестала 403-я вылезать. Правда один чёрт не приходит то что надо. Но на заметку возьму такой способ обхода)

Comment: странно, я добавил все заголовки, но мне это не помогло, ошибка также 403