# Python пустой html файл при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер

При запросе к сайту создается html файл, но заместо кода сайта такая вот шляпа. Где допустил ошибку?

Мой код пайтона:

```
import datetime
from unicodedata import name
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


def collect_data(city_code='0221'):
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%y_%h_%m')

    ua = UserAgent()


    headers = {
        'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
        'User-Agent': ua.random
    }

    cookies = {
        'mg_geo_id' : f'{city_code}'
    }

    response = requests.get(url='https://magnit.ru/promo/' , headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

    with open(f'index.html' , 'w') as file:
        file.write(response.text)


def main():
    collect_data(city_code='0221')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Информация в HTMLL файле:
Forbidden
Transaction ID: 26e16f51-57f6-41ae-83d9-94a258061060
```

Answer (score 0):

403 ошибку выдает при запросе. Может сайт понимает, что это бот и блокирует.
Попробуйте Selenium driver для имитации работы пользователя.

Есть похожий ответ ([Python 3.x. HTTP Error 403: Forbidden (даже с "User-agent")](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269604/python-3-x-http-error-403-forbidden-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81-user-agent))

Comment: решил проблему перекодировкой   with open(f'index.html' , 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(response.text)